# how do I override JUST the constructor in a Groovy class?

Tags: groovy, constructor

I would like to override ONLY the behavior of the constructor in a groovy class.  Like so

```
class Foo {
    def a
    def b

    Foo(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
        println("I'm a Foo!")
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    Bar(int a, int b) {
        this.a = 2*a
        this.b = 2*b
        println("I'm a Bar!")
    }
}

def f = new Foo(1, 2)
def b = new Bar(1, 2)
```

when I run this, the `def f = new Foo(1, 2)` line run successfully, but `def bar = new Bar(1, 2)` throws an exception:

```
I'm a Foo!
Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Foo: method <init>()V not found
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Foo: method <init>()V not found
```

So I'm confused here.  How do I override ONLY the constructor of a class property.

(incidentally, IntelliJ is complaining about the definition of the `Bar` constructor, saying 'There is no default constructor available in class Foo'), and that is confusing to me as well.

**UPDATE**:

I found that I could solve the problem by adding a no-arg constructor to Foo as `Foo() {}`.  And that seems to solve the problem with Bar.  But I still have no idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groovy based on java and in java you can't override constructor of ancestor. you can only extend it.

if you are not specifying which constructor to extend by using `super(a, b)` (for example) - then compiler will try to use default parent constructor `super()` - and here you got an original error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Foo: method ()V not found

so, this one should work:

```
class Foo {
    def a
    def b
    
    String toString(){ "${this.getClass()}[$a, $b]" }

    Foo(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
        println("I'm a Foo!")
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    Bar(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b)    // <<-- the only change
        this.a = 2*a
        this.b = 2*b
        println("I'm a Bar!")
    }
}

def f = new Foo(1, 2)
def b = new Bar(1, 2)

println f
println b
```

result:

```
I'm a Foo!
I'm a Foo!    <<-- this is coming from Bar (inherited from Foo)
I'm a Bar!
class Foo[1, 2]
class Bar[2, 4]
```

Comment: ahh...I was not aware of the restriction that you can only extend a constructor in Java, not override it.   Now it makes sense!  Thanks!